# How to push data to client using node

Tags: node.js

I'm using node to make an email client. I want to update the browser window as soon as any new email arrives. I'm already fetching the emails on server side using mail-listener2. I want to push that data to client side. How do i do that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Look at using **websockets** to push data in realtime to the client (browser). I would recommend using http://socket.io. They have some really great demos on there to show how you would do something like this.

Your server would send socket.io messages called `message`, containing the message details as JSON. Your client would listen for `message` events and update the UI as they come in.